# How to exclude tags with Maven Surefire via command line options?

Tags: java, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I'm trying to exclude a tag from test execution with Java system props that are passed via the command line, but it's not working.

```
public class A {

    @Test
    @Tag("NotThreadSafe")
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("NotThreadSafe");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("It's ok");
    }
}
```

`$: mvn clean test -Dtest="**/selftest/**" -DexcludeTags="NotThreadSafe"`

**Output:**

```
NotThreadSafe
It's ok
```

But -Dgroups propery works fine:

`$: mvn clean test -Dtest="**/cdp/autotests/selftest/**" -Dgroups="NotThreadSafe"`

**Output:**

```
NotThreadSafe
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned here:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1612#issuecomment-426217199

We need to use [Tag expressions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions)

```
mvn clean test -Dtest="**/selftest/**" -Dgroups=\!NotThreadSafe
```